# Getting a "Failure to connect to Windows Service (Group Policy Client Services)" error

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm getting this error, `Failure to connect to Windows Service (Group Policy Client Services)` on my laptop, but only some times. It's very irritating, because it is not consistent. My daughter was just using it fine, and she is just an ordinary user on the laptop.

She logged off and I logged in (and I'm an Administrator on that laptop) and then I got this error message. I was logged in at least twice today previously, without this error popping up at all. I just rebooted the system, let my daughter in and she didn't get the error message at all.

So why is this coming up only sometimes? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOURCE LINK:** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/windows-81-error-with-group-policy-client/f04c0fb6-8d99-4632-8601-a7aae31a7e5d

**Method 1:** Run an SFC Scan
The “sfc /scannow” command scans all protected system files and replaces incorrect versions with correct Microsoft versions.

- a) Press `Windows Logo + Q` keys on the keyboard and type “`cmd`” in
  the search box.
- b) Right click on the `Command Prompt` icon from the search results
  and select `Run as administrator`
- c) On the command prompt window, type the following command `sfc /scannow`, and then press `Enter`
- d) Follow the on-screen instructions and complete the scan. If the
  issue persists, then I would suggest you to try the next method and
  check the status.

**Method 2:** Fix the Missing the Registry Entries

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/windows-8-group-policy-client-service-failed-sign/7ce8e193-6651-4f8f-b2c3-28de3d389b1a